# Post-Processing and Execution of Paths from Sampling-Based Planning: Refinement, Shortcutting, and Real-World Dynamics

Tags: moveit, motion-planning, path-planning

I've been diving into sampling-based approaches for path planning, such as RRT (Rapidly-exploring Random Trees) and PRM (Probabilistic Roadmaps), along with their extensions. While I understand the basic concepts of generating paths using these algorithms, I'm a bit unclear on the subsequent steps.

From my understanding, the entire process, from generating the path to executing the real trajectory, follows these steps:

1. Path generation using the sampling-based approach.
2. Shortcutting the generated path to eliminate redundant nodes. From my research, this step often employs random pair shortcutting.
3. Time parametrization of the simplified path to produce the final trajectory.
4. Execution of the trajectory on the real robot, with interpolation from one waypoint to the next handled internally by the robot controller.

Given the above, I have a few questions:

- The path generated in step 1 is collision-free based on its parameter setup. However, when applying the shortcutting, how is the collision-free nature ensured, especially if multiple nodes are bypassed? For instance, if the path was initially generated with specific node spacing for collision checks, how is this addressed during shortcutting?
- How is time parametrization applied? The resulting configurations are typically linear. Is this approach effective, especially for its derivatives?
- Can the robot controller's interpolation potentially introduce collisions into the trajectory? If so, is this mitigated by maintaining a minimal spacing between waypoints?

Any insights, corrections, references, or experiences you could share would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean with short cutting? RRT shouldn't do that. RRT star does a rewiring wich is different.

Comment: I'm referring to the post-processing of the path, not the sampling based algorithm itself. As far as I know, the output of the sampling based algorithm (RRT, PRM, RRTstar, ...) is post-processed, in this process shortcuts are normally applied to remove redundant nodes.